# VMIN and VTIME Terminal Settings for variable sized messages

Tags: c, terminal, serial-port

I'm trying to interface with a device via the serial port. The device sends out a `10 byte` poll as a "heartbeat" every 700ms. Everytime I read the heartbeat I have to reply with a `12 byte` long response.

Within this response I can request that the device sends particular data inbetween polls. The amount of data is different for different requests. Is there a way to set up the serial port such that it will always read messages in one chunk regardless of their size?

My current terminal settings are as follows:

```
int ttySetRaw(int fd, struct termios *prevTermios)
{
    struct termios t;
    if (tcgetattr(fd, &t) == -1)
        return -1;

    if (prevTermios != NULL)
        *prevTermios = t;

    t.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ISIG | IEXTEN | ECHO);
    t.c_iflag &= ~(BRKINT | ICRNL | IGNBRK | IGNCR | INLCR | INPCK | ISTRIP | IXON | PARMRK);
    t.c_oflag &= ~OPOST; /* Disable all output processing */
    t.c_cc[VMIN] = 12; /* 12 chars at a time, enough for the poll and the reply to be sent/received in one chunk, when I change this I no longer receive the poll*/
    t.c_cc[VTIME] = 10; /* maximum timeout 1 second */

    t.c_cflag |= PARENB;
    t.c_cflag |= PARODD;

    if (tcsetattr(fd, TCSAFLUSH, &t) == -1)
       return -1;

    return 0;
}
```

I've tried changing VMIN and VTIME, I thought setting VTIME = 7 would mean it would read everything in the buffer until 700ms had passed, but this fails. It would also not be sufficient for the times when I want the device to send another, longer, message inside the polling interval.

Is there a setup that would be able to achieve what I want, or am I going to have to byte the bullet and read the data one byte at a time and build the messages up in a separate function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to set up the serial port such that it will always read
>   messages in  one chunk regardless of their size?

In general, no.  Like TCP streams, serial links are byte streams and have no message-boundaries bigger than one byte.

You need a protocol that allows the messages to be parsed out of the byte stream.

That said, some serial hardware and drivers allow a 'break' signal to be sent and detected, but I don't know anyone who uses that feture any more, even if available.

Comment: Thanks, I've set VTIME = 1, and VMIN = 255. As I understand this will read everything in the buffer (up to 255 bytes) in 0.1s. I guess I'll have to process the buffer after.

Comment: @Kells1986 - if you rely on just timing, without an appropriate protocol, you will get problems later, even if everything seems to work in your test environment at the moment.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for more reliably reading the appropriate amount of data?