# Reading variable length data from serial with timeout

Tags: c, serial-port, buffer

I am reading data frames from a device using a software UART driver. It's written as a tty module so reading from is is pretty standard:

```
struct termios options;
int tty = open(path, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY  | O_SYNC);
tcgetattr(tty, &options);
options.c_cflag = B4800 | CS8 | CLOCAL | CREAD | PARENB;
options.c_iflag = IGNPAR;
options.c_oflag = 0;
options.c_lflag = 0;
tcsetattr(tty, TCSANOW, &options);
while (running)
{
    int rx_count = read(tty_device, (void*)header, header_size);
    // parse the header to figure out the total frame size
    rx_count = read(tty_device, (void*)frame_data, frame_size);
}
```

It works most of the time, but sometimes I miss some bytes due to limitations in the reliability of the UART.

My problem is that when I miss bytes the code reads the initial bytes of the next frame as the final bytes of the previous frame. This causes random, unpredictable behavior.

I am wondering if there is a good way to read based on time, instead of data size. Something like this:

```
while (running)
{
    // read bytes continuously from the tty device
    // if 1 second passes with no further bytes coming, stop reading
    // process whatever data was read
}
```

I could probably hack together something that does this eventually but I imagine there is a good chance this has already been figured out, and I am just failing to find the info on the internet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement a timeout in read function call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917881/how-to-implement-a-timeout-in-read-function-call)

Comment: Do the frames you read have a specific format? Perhaps with a start-of-frame and end-of-frame markers that are unique and easily recognizable? Then you could read byte by byte from the start-of-frame until the end-of-frame, and if you find a start-of-frame marker before the end-of-frame, then you know the packet was corrupted.

Comment: Considering that you cannot modify the structure of the frame, a timeout could  be useful (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html)

Comment: You can also make the descriptor non-blocking and read until there's an error with `errno == EWOULDBLOCK`. Possibly combine with my previous suggestion.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude unfortunately, though there is a frame start marker, it's just one byte and this byte may also appear in the frame data.

Comment: @Jose I was thinking something similar as well, but was wondering if there was a better way.

Comment: *"sometimes I miss some bytes due to limitations in the reliability of the UART"* -- No, do not blame the UART unless you can prove that UART overruns are actually occurring.  FYI your code "reads" from a buffer, not the UART.   Your termios configuration is suboptimal and incomplete.  You apparently have no idea if it's canonical mode or raw mode.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25996171/linux-blocking-vs-non-blocking-serial-read/26006680#26006680

Comment: @sawdust It's not a UART but a software UART, and I know it's missing bytes because I see it mistiming reads on my protocol analyzer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to accomplish what I need using VMIN and VTIME as found in the link from the comment of sawdust:
[Linux Blocking vs. non Blocking Serial Read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25996171/linux-blocking-vs-non-blocking-serial-read/26006680#26006680)

This was also relevant to my problem. Somehow I couldn't figure out the right search terms to find it before:
[VMIN and VTIME Terminal Settings for variable sized messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19787265/vmin-and-vtime-terminal-settings-for-variable-sized-messages)